# gets not working properly to write in a file

Tags: c, file-io

I made a following program.The program shows no compiler error. There exist a file alive.txt in the directory. I want to use gets to write string to the file alive.txt but its not working properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *myfile;
    char c,d;
    char e[100];
    myfile=fopen("alive.txt","r");

    if(!myfile)
    {
        puts("Disk Error");
        return(1);
    }

    while((c=fgetc(myfile))!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
    }

    puts("\n");
    puts("Do ya want to overwrite this file:{Y/N}");// 
    d=toupper(getchar());

    if(d!='Y')
    {
        puts("Ok.. See ya Later");
        return(1);
    }

    myfile=fopen("alive.txt","w");
    puts("Type The Character to overwrite");
    gets(e);  // scanf works               
    fprintf(myfile,"%s",e);
    fclose(myfile);

    getch();
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: Please add what it does -- "not working properly" is not a proper description.

Comment: What is your input string? Show the input and the file content also.

Comment: As soon as i press any key the program terminates. I was entering my name.

Comment: And Using a getch() instead of getchar also worked since getch does not require a newline.

Comment: Don't use `gets()`.  Don't ever use `gets()`.  Never, *never*, **never**, ***never***, ***NEVER*** use `gets()`.  No program that uses `gets()` can protect itself from abuse.  The first Internet worm used `gets()` to propagate itself (Google 'morris internet worm').  At long last, `gets()` is not a part of standard C; it was removed from the C11 standard. Use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) instead.

Comment: The problem is that `gets()` reads the newline after the `Y` and realizes 'end of line', and returns an empty string (because it removes the newline), so there's nothing written to the file. If you use `scanf("%s", e);` instead of `gets()`, the `%s` format skips leading white space (such as the newline after the `Y`) and reads the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `gets()` reads the newline after the `Y` and realizes 'end of line', and returns an empty string (because it removes the newline), so there's nothing written to the file. If you use `scanf("%s", e);` instead of `gets()`, the `%s` format skips leading white space (such as the newline after the `Y`) and reads the next word.

Other problems include:

- You're also leaking file descriptors (file streams) because you don't `fclose()` the `myFile` from the first `fopen()`.
- You're using `gets()` which is, as stated in a comment, a very bad idea.  (Teachers who suggest using `gets()` should be forcibly restrained from teaching; students who use `gets()` should be given 0 marks automatically.)  Don't use `gets()`; use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or
  [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) instead.  Note that `fgets()` includes the newline in the data if there's space for it.
- You're using `char c;` and then trying to detect EOF with it — which is unreliable.
- You don't check that your `fopen()` calls succeed; you use the file pointer anyway, which will cause your program to crash if the file isn't there for any reason.

Answer (score 2):

The file is already open for reading from when you open it for writing to. Add

```
fclose(myfile);
```

before the second `fopen`.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter since before it was opened for reading only. And also, OP says that `scanf` works.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay I don't know whether the standard says anything about the behavior of `fprintf` when a file was opened for reading and was opened for writing before being closed for reading. Also, `scanf` doesn't use `myfile`. Its behavior should not depend on the state of `myfile`.

Comment: You don't get it. OP used `scanf` instead of `gets` and it _seems_ that it worked.

Comment: What does `scanf` have anything to do with `myfile`? The problems are associated with only using `myfile`.

Comment: I know. But the OP says `gets(e);  // scanf works  `. So what I'm saying is that maybe it isn't the problem with not closing before writing. And as it turns out, it is [not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714157/gets-not-working-properly-to-write-in-a-file/23714251?noredirect=1#comment36445170_23714157).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<conio.h> Non-portable
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *myfile;
    char c,d;
    char e[100];

    myfile=fopen("alive.txt","r");
    if(!myfile)
    {
        puts("Disk Error");
        return(1);
    }

    /* Show the current file content. */
    while((c=fgetc(myfile))!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(myFile);   //  Close the read-only file mode. 
    puts("\n");

    puts("Do ya want to overwrite this file:{Y/N}");
    d=toupper(getchar());
    if(d!='Y')
    {
        puts("Ok.. See ya Later");
        return(1);
    }

    /*Flush '\n' character from stdin */
    getchar();

    puts("Type The Characters used to overwrite");
    gets(e);  // scanf works

    myfile=fopen("alive.txt","w"); Re-open in write mode, deleting old file content.
    fprintf(myfile,"%s",e);
    fclose(myfile);

//  getch(); Non-portable

    /* Be nice and close the file when finished with it. */
    fclose(myfile);
    return(0);
}
```